# How to write a while loop in Rego in OPA

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent, rego

I have a requirement to write a Rego policy that expands an object and build a new one, after referring a data source.

Input comes with

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "roles": [
        "admin",
        "developer"
      ]
    },
    "userid2": {
      "roles": [
        "developer",
        "manager"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is a separate data source

```
{
  "roles": {
    "admin": [
      "create",
      "delete"
    ],
    "developer": [
      "update",
      {"view" : ["A"] }
    ],
    "manager": [
      {"view" : ["B"] }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output (expanding the roles of each user based on datasource)

```
{
  "users": {
    "userid1": {
      "roles": [
        "create",
        "delete",
        "update",
        "view" : ["A"]
      ]
    },
    "userid2": {
      "roles": [
        "view" : ["A", "B"],
        "update"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have developed below policy to build the new object for users expanding the details from datasource. But it has a problem, because it only works when there are only 2 roles, as my merge function can merge only two. For example if a user has 3 or more roles this fails. Ideally I need something similar to a while loop which can go through all the roles of the user and expand them into a single roles array which can iteratively use the merge function.

**Policy**

```
scopes := merged {
role_count = count(users.userid1["roles"])
merged = merge_scopes(data.datasources.roles[role_count-1]],data.datasources.roles[role_count-2]])
}


has_key(x, k) { _ = x[k] }

merge_values(k, a, b) = a[k]{
not has_key(b, k)
}

merge_values(k, a, b) = b[k]{
not has_key(a, k) 
}

merge_values(k, a, b) = c{
has_key(a, k) 
has_key(b, k)
c := array.concat(a[k],b[k])
}

merge_scopes(a, b) = c {
    ks := {k | some k; _ = a[k]} | {k | some k; _ = b[k]}
    c := {k: v | some k; ks[k]; v := merge_values(k, b, a)}
}
```

Looking forward for a solution to improve this merge function when more than 2 or any number of roles present for the user.